# Twodiemensional Array of booleans in PROGMEM(AVR) on arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino

I'm trying to construct an two dimensional array on an arduino uno which uses an atmega328. I want an array of booleans with the size of 256 * 18. This is to big for the 2KB RAM so i wanted to  save it to the PROGMEM(avr). how can i do this and how can i acces the variables? i found some tutotials about doing th same with chars or strings but there is no data type for booleans. what is the best way zo save and extract booleans in/from chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have likely read about using program space (aka flash). It is necassary to use special macro's that work on the pointers, as detailed at [avr-libc/user-manual](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html).

That said, see my example of a 2D matrix in program space example of [storing the 2D array](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/SFEMP3Shield.cpp#L25) along with the example of [calling the data from the 2D array](https://github.com/mpflaga/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/blob/master/SFEMP3Shield/SFEMP3Shield.cpp#L1620)

It should work for larger scale.

Where you sneak a second question at the end, about booleans. Note booleans while treated as 0 or 1 really consume a full byte.

You may want to consider #include  and using the [vector< bool >](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) type as this will consume only a single bit per unit. As each element occupies a single bit.

Comment: Thanks, i read the data wrong, i tried to access elements of the array with array[i][j].